# Laravel eloquent update JSON column some fields without overriding everything else

Tags: eloquent, mysql-json

We are trying to use [JSON datatypes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json.html) to store `Profile` dynamic data, and do not know all of the hard-coded field names to add to the `fillable` property in model. how to set (`insert` if the key not exists | `update` if the key exists) just one key, not all of them?

For example if we want to update just `age` and we use:

```
$model = Profile::find($profile_id);
$model->options = json_encode(['age' => '21']);
$model->save();
```

this solution isn't a great option, because it overrides everything else.
How can we set just the desired fields without changing other fields (JSON keys)?

Comment: This is your best option in Laravel: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#updating-json-columns You can replace `DB::table('...')` with `Profile::query()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution in pure mysql is:

```
UPDATE `profiles`
SET `data` = JSON_SET(
    `data` ,
    '$.age' ,
    '21'
)
WHERE
    `id` = 1;
```

The `JSON_SET` function will add the property if it is not found else replace it. [read more here](https://scotch.io/tutorials/working-with-json-in-mysql#toc-update)

But in Laravel you should ensure that the model's `$fillable` property has the column in it:

```php
$fillable = [
    ...
    "data->age",
    ...
];
```

then you can use:

```php
Profile::find($profile_id)->update([
   'data->age' => 21,
]);
```